# Python plotting time list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Sorry for my bad English.

I have a list :

```
found_time = ['2019-02-28 00:24:16', '2019-02-28 00:22:30', '2019-02-27 08:08:21', ... ... , '2019-02-01 22:21:10', '2019-02-01 00:21:10']
```

[image: expected plot]

and I am trying to make plot table like ↑this one.
and [Chris A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10201580/chris-a) gave me a code which plots like ↓this.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    s = pd.Series(np.ones(len(found_time)), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(found_time))
    s = s.resample('H').sum()

    plt.scatter(s.index.hour, s.index.date, s=s, color='k')

    # yticks
    yticks = pd.date_range('2019-02-01', '2019-02-28', freq='D')
    plt.yticks(yticks, [y.strftime('%m-%d') for y in yticks])
    plt.ylim('2019-02-01', '2019-02-28')

    # xticks
    xticks = np.arange(24)
    plt.xticks(xticks, ['{0:02d}:00'.format(x) for x in xticks], rotation=45,ha='right')
```

[image: result plot]

and the problem is it only plots on exact time. 
ex)08:45:33 -> 08:00, 07:12:09 -> 07:00

> **Question:** How do you plot more precisely? Not hourly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = pd.Series(np.ones(len(found_time)), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(found_time))

plt.scatter(s.index.time, s.index.date, color='k')

# yticks
yticks = pd.date_range('2019-02-01', '2019-02-28', freq='D')
plt.yticks(yticks, [y.strftime('%m-%d') for y in yticks])
plt.ylim('2019-02-01', '2019-02-28')


# xticks
xticks = pd.date_range('00:00', '23:00', freq='H').time
plt.xticks(xticks, [x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in xticks], rotation=45,ha='right')
```

pay attention: `plt.scatter(s.index.time, s.index.date, color='k')`

and `xticks` can compare with `s.index.time`